# How to make the regex from .replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) safe for Userinput?

Tags: java, replaceall

In a programm like this:

```
String userInput = "[]";
String str = "Hello World[]!";
String replacement = "";
str = str.replaceAll(userInput, replacement);
System.out.print(str);
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 1
[]
```

But I want the ouput:

```
Hello World!
```

Is there are way to make userInput safe for replaceAll? Let's say the userInput is: `[]`. How do I need to process the String to always replace the String an not the meaning of the String.

Comment: Please provide examples. Your problem description is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the user's text to be interpreted as a regex, just use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

```java
String str = "foo bar [] baz []";
String userInput = "[]";
String replacement = "moo";
str = str.replace(userInput, replacement);
// str = "foo bar moo baz moo"
```

Note that it replaces *all* occurrences of the target. The naming is a little unfortunate. Here's a summary of that the `String#replace*` methods do:

- `replace`: replaces all verbatim occurrences.
- `replaceFirst`: replaces the first regex match.
- `replaceAll`: replaces all regex matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly [`quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) input strings:

```
String normal = "[]";
System.out.println(normal);
System.out.println(Pattern.quote(normal));
```

> []
>   \Q[]\E